# Java Multiple Queries not executing

Tags: java, sql, oracle

With the following code I am getting `java.lang.RuntimeException: Connection failed :ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement`.The first query gets executed but the later ones don't.

Code :

```
Connection conn = Pool.getConnection();
logWithTimestamp("Connection Established" +conn);
Statement stmt = null;
String [] queries = createQuery.split("#");
for(String q :queries){
    logWithTimestamp("Executing query " +q);
    stmt =conn.createStatement();
    stmt.execute(q);
    stmt.close();
    }
conn.close();
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: are you sure there isn't any request which is not written with bad sql syntax ? could you print out the log ?

Comment: You want us to tell you what's wrong with an SQL statement that you haven't shown us?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using split, I would suggest you debug your code within the loop and check for the String q you get in the second iteration, If the first query is running fine, then there is no problem with the Connection, It is the loop where the problem lies.

I guess the string is not split correctly. Kindly do check the queries array as well when you debug your program.